# MVC 5 Optional Parameter Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, action, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to know how to do below scenario using mvc 5 routing

My url structure

http://www.xx.com/search/1

http://www.xx.com/search/cat/1

http://www.xx.com/search/cat/prod/1

```
[Route("search/{cat?}/{prod?}/{pageId:int=1}")]
public ActionResult Index(string cat, string prod, int pageId)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below for your scenario:

```
[Route("search/{pageId:int=1}")]
[Route("search/{cat}/{pageId:int=1}")] //
[Route("search/{cat}/{prod}/{pageId:int=1}")]
public ActionResult Index(string cat, string prod, int pageId)
{
   ....
}
```